# Entity Framework Core: Query only a few properties of related entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have related entities `Teams` and `Playlists`, where a `Team` can hold multiple `Playlists`. Now, from a given team, I need all the playlists, but only the `Id` and `PlaylistName` properties.

I tried this, but it returns Anonymous Types within the list, that is hard to map to my PlaylistDTO.

```
var data = await (from team in _context.Teams
    where team.Id == teamId //teamId comes from incoming request
    select new
    {
       Id = team.Playlists.Select(pl => pl.Id),
       PlayListName = team.Playlists.Select(pl => pl.PlayListName)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

`data` is of type `List<'a> , 'a is a new { IEnumerable<Int> Id, IEnumerable<string> PlaylistName }`

The statement below works, but is not what I want, since it gets me all the properties from the Playlist entity.

```
Team team = await _context.Teams
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(t => t.Playlists)
    .Where(t => t.Id == teamId)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

My two entities: 
Team

```
public class Team
{
   public int Id {get; set; }
   public string TeamName { get; set; }
   //... more properties
   public ICollection<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }
}
```

Playlist

```
public class Playlist
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string PlaylistName {get; set; }
   // .. other properties
   public int? TeamId { get; set; }
   public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get only the desired properties of the related entity, without being returned an Anonymous Type?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the problem? Instead of projecting to anonymous object - project to DTO.

Comment: You can simply ```where team.Id == teamId //teamId comes from incoming request
    select new dataDTO
    {
       Id = team.Playlists.Select(pl => pl.Id),
       PlayListName = team.Playlists.Select(pl => pl.PlayListName)
    }).ToListAsync();```


Where dataDTO is your object.

Comment: Create a view model. Load your playlist and use automapper to map properties from your playlist to your view model and then hand handover your view model. Done.

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix the classes from your domain and the responses that your system gives.

I would create a new class to represent this DTO (Data Transfer Object)

```cs
public class ResponseDTO
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }
}
```

In your query use this new class instead of the anonymous object

```
var data = await (from team in _context.Teams
    where team.Id == teamId
    select new ResponseDTO
    {
       Id = team.Playlists.Select(pl => pl.Id),
       PlayListName = team.Playlists.Select(pl => pl.PlayListName)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Take a look in the concept of [Domain Driven Design](https://medium.com/microtica/the-concept-of-domain-driven-design-explained-3184c0fd7c3f) to understand the importance of leaving the classes that compose your domain only responsible for that.